# How do I allow WebSockets connection with HTTPS in AWS EC2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I have a chat made with the library RatchetPHP, but I don't know how to allows websockets connection with https, my chat works only with http, when I try to use with SSL, it give me error in G Console: error connection timed out.


So, how can I allow websockets connection under https?

Do I need to make reverse proxy? And how can I do it?

What is the best to use for this, apache or nginx? Explain me why

Is it okay to use Let's Encrypt as the SSL? Does it affect websockets connection?

Comment: This is a webserver configuration question. Your question is: How do I set up HTTPS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to WebSocket using Ratchet + SSL in EC2 with Apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/1033290/cant-connect-to-websocket-using-ratchet-ssl-in-ec2-with-apache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, how can I allow websockets connection under https?

Generally you would allow https (TCP 443) through your firewall, then configure your web server to accept those connections. Now that you know this you can search for "(web server) accept websocket connections".

> Do I need to make reverse proxy? And how can I do it?

No you don't need a reverse proxy. You might like to use a load balancer if you think you'll need to scale out, but you don't need one to start. A bit of reading on what a reverse proxy does might help you understand.

> What is the best to use for this, apache or nginx? Explain me why

Either is fine. I use Nginx as it's simpler to configure and light weight.

> Is it okay to use Let's Encrypt as the SSL? Does it affect websockets
> connection?

Yes, the certificate issuer is not material to this use case.

Comment: Thank you so much, it really helped me!

Comment: btw, the first point about tcp port 443 is generally true however it doesn't only constraint to utilization of the above mentioned value and thus completely arbitrary for the developement stage